# Google maps API help or List indices output

Tags: python

I have an excel sheet with a bunch of info regarding the stops a 
delivery truck makes throughout the day.  I can successfully extract 
the information I need with xlrd.  This is the code I am using:

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook(r'c:\xytest.xls') 
sheet= book.sheet_by_index(0) 
odList = [] 
for i in range(1,6125): 
   cID = sheet.row(i)[0].value #Company ID 
   tID = sheet.row(i)[1].value #Truck ID 
   xyCoord = sheet.row_values(i,start_colx = 8,end_colx = 10 ) #long 
   and lat 
   xyCoord.reverse() #reversed, so that lat,long is in correct format 
   odList.append([cID,tID,xyCoord])
```

Printing odList give me this output where fields are:

```
[CompanyID,TruckID, Lat,Long] I get [[5000020.0, 1.0, [35.779999, 
-78.115784]], [5000020.0, 1.0, [36.075812, -78.256766]], [5000020.0, 
1.0, [35.779999, -78.115784]], [5000020.0, 2.0, [35.79528, 
-78.137549]], [5000020.0, 3.0, [35.79528, -78.137549]]
```

I used list indices to grab the coordinates and query gmaps with:

```
result = gmaps.directions(odList[0][2],odList[1][2]) 
time = result['Directions']['Duration']['seconds'] 
dist = result['Directions']['Distance']['meters']
```

Unfortunately, gmaps does not understand [35.779999, -78.115784], 
[36.075812, -78.256766], gmaps does understand (35.779999, -78.115784), 
(36.075812, -78.256766).  Any ideas on how to get the query to send () 
instead of [] ? `

Comment: gmaps shoudn't care whether you supply lists or tuples ... what is the error message that you get?

Answer (score 1):

Try using an tuple `(var1, var2)` or `(var,)` instead of a list `[var1, var2]`, or convert the lists to tuples before sending printing `tuple([var])`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
xyCoord = sheet.row_values(i,start_colx = 8,end_colx = 10 ) #long and lat 
xyCoord.reverse() #reversed, so that lat,long is in correct format 
odList.append([cID,tID,xyCoord])
```

do this:

```
lon, lat = sheet.row_values(i, start_colx=8, end_colx=10)
odList.append([cID, tID, (lat, lon))
```